# How do you check if a path is valid in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a simple feature where you can pass a `destination` query parameter to the `/login` page that causes you to be redirected to that that page instead of the default behavior I have set.

The destination is stored in session and then used later to redirect inside of my LoginController.

Here is my snippet:

```
if ($destination = session('login_redirect')) { . 
    $route = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($destination));
    $destination_route = route($route->getName(), $route->parameters());
}
```

I need to only redirect if the path is valid and I want to check that before deciding redirecting. By valid, I mean it's a URL that Laravel will return a 200 for. Right now when the path is valid I'm (logically) getting a `NotFoundHttpException` when I call `app('request')->create()` to turn the path into a route.

Is the only way to do some shenanigans in the `render()` function in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`? If so, I'm not clear how to distinguish between a valid 404 (a user page request) and the exception I'm getting by creating a request programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking whether $destination variable is set and is not empty, if so just redirect to that given destination.

else, ($destination was set in session but doesn't match to any routes present in your app) throw a new exception and name it whatever you want, and then just finally catch that exception in `app/Exceptions/handler.php` , or you could just simply redirect to default path in this else statement. Code would look like this:

```
$destination = session('login_redirect')
if ($destination && $destination != "" )) {
    try {
        $route = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($destination));
        $destination_route = route($route->getName(), $route->parameters());
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e
        // OR
        throw new Myexception;
    }
}
else {
    return redirect("foobar");
    // OR
    throw new MyException;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the try/catch doesn't catch the `NotFoundHttpException` exception.

Comment: then i guess your best bet could be to catch that exception in your handler.php like so.
`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
{
    // Your stuff here
}`